# Java Spring boot 2.0.5 MultipartFile upload "Content type not supported"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipart

I have a project with Spring boot and I'm trying to upload a file.

I'm using multipart/form-data on my form and @RequestPart in my Controller. Although all the tutorials and solutions recommended to use @RequestParam, it doesn't seem to work anymore or just for me.

I got over the problem of not getting the post request parameter by using @RequestPart but now the browser gives @Content type not supported" error.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="offset-3 col-6">
                <form method="post" action="/save" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
package com.tantsurepertuaar.tantsurepertuaar.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;




@Controller
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String save(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
        //saving file
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tantsurepertuaar</groupId>
    <artifactId>tantsurepertuaar</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>tantsurepertuaar</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>-->
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I have a feeling that it might have something to do with being newer versions of Spring boot for example. 
I tried out example on page http://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-file-upload-example/ and it worked but when I used the same HTML and Controller in my project then I got the same error as before.

Thanks

Comment: did you debug and check what error server side is showing?? check spring boot logs and put a debug point in controller to see if at-least controller method is hitting or not even hitting??

Comment: I hav checked it and there is nothing in logs. Controller method is not hitting and the log just says that failed to handle request.

Comment: I used all your configurations and for me works

Comment: Have you tried to specify the content type with
`@PostMapping(value = ["/save"], consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])`

Comment: I don't know why but starting out the project again from scratch worked.

Answer (score 0):

and add the following in application.properties

```
multipart.enabled=true
multipart.file-size-threshold=0 # Threshold after which files will be written to disk.
multipart.location=# Intermediate location of uploaded files.
multipart.max-file-size=1Mb # Max file size.
multipart.max-request-size=10Mb # Max request size.
```